# how to prevent gson from escaping characters?

Tags: escaping, gson

I have a problem with gson, whitch is escaping my string.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
String test = "\r\n";
JsonElement result = gson.toJsonTree(test);            
String string = gson.toJson(result);
```

After this string is `"\\r\\n"` How to avoid this?

Comment: I just tried your code with Gson 2.2.4 and `string` is not escaped (anymore).